# How did Hitchcock get the still eyeball shot in "Psycho"?

Tags: effects, cinematography, psycho

In the 1960 thriller *Psycho*, there is a shot of a dead body with the eye fixed open as the corpse lays on the bathroom floor. At first I thought it was a still, but some of the water drops move, so I wonder how did Hitchcock, the director, get a multisecond shot of the body with the eye open and not blinking?

[image]
My guess is that a still photograph was used and they just dripped a real water drop down the photograph to give the illusion that it was a live shot.

Comment: Not sure it's an exact dupe, but it's an extension of this method - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93569/how-do-actors-stop-breathing-when-playing-dead

Comment: The first part, where it's tight on the eyeball, is clearly a still, but as it zooms out it transitions to a live shot - I think you can see Janet Leigh's throat move slightly.  I don't know how she kept her eyes so still - maybe she took some kind of relaxant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the most part, **this is simply Janet Leigh toughing it out and trying her damnedest not to blink**. Leigh described the process in [this interview to Woman's World](https://www.womansworld.com/posts/janet-leigh-psycho-154863), and here's an excerpt:

> There is also a shot — that seems to go on forever — where the camera is locked on Marion’s dead eye, and Janet somehow never blinks. Not once. **Some have suggested that this was a still photo that had sprinkles of water applied to it.**
>
> **"That is not true," she says.** "About three weeks before we shot it, **Mr. Hitchcock and I went off to the optometrists.
>   He wanted me to put in those lenses that would give me a scary look.** At the time — remember, we’re talking late 1959/early 1960 — for me to wear those lenses would’ve taken six weeks for my eyes to get used to them. And if I didn't, it could have damaged my eyes.
>
> **Mr. Hitchcock said, 'Well, you can’t do that.' I said, 'No, we can’t,' and he replied, 'You’re just going to have to do it on your own.' So I held that look. It’s not a photograph, goddamnit!"** She broke into a smile. "I will say it wasn’t easy."

There are a few caveats, though (detailed in [this interesting BFI article](https://www.bfi.org.uk/news-opinion/news-bfi/interviews/psycho-shower-scene-alfred-hitchcock) about this scene):

- During the *dissolve* from the shower drain to her eye, that *is* a still frame of the eye (due to technological constraints - they couldn't combine them otherwise);
- You can see that it then goes back to real time (and that it *really is* Leigh staring unblinkingly) because in the only usable take
  they had out of 26(!), *her eye twitches the slightest bit*. Keep your eyes on her lower eyelid at 0:54-0:57 in the clip below and you might be able to spot it;
- Again, as this was the only usable take, they had to hide the fact that Leigh also *took a breath* - which they mostly obscured by cutting briefly to the showerhead then back to her, but *you can still see her throat contracting a little* (from 1:04 onward).